# Border causing floats to stack

Tags: css, border

The following code produces two nice colunms and a footer:

```
<div class="column one">
ONE
</div>

<div class="column two">
TWO
</div>

<div class="footer">
Footer
</div>​
```

with css:

```
.column {float: right; width: 30%; margin: 0 10%;}
.footer {clear: both;}
```

So why when I add a border the two columns suddenly stack on top of each other?

```
.column, .footer {
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
 }
```

See - fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usdu7/19/

Comment: The borders account for an element's width as well as padding, margin and the width itself. You have to remove the border width from the element width to make it work as expected.

Comment: The border is just adding to the overall width that your divs are taking up. Try changing the width of the margin and border to find a combination you like.

Comment: So how can I represent the columns width in percentages and still have a border?

Comment: WEll there is the brand new `calc()` function in CSS3, but it's widely unused so... `box-sizing: border-box;` is probably your safest bet right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because, border adds to the width. So the total width is 4 pixel more than 100% width. So, it stacks over each other.

Adding box-sizing property will solve the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/usdu7/30/

Comment: What's the difference between: display: box; and box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: As far as I know there's no box value for display property. May be you are referring to display: block;